# Does CImageList removes resources?

Tags: c++, mfc, resource-leak

I have came across with a GDI leaking problem in our project so I started to search for possible issues. I have found a place where the implementor created new instances of icons with LoadIcon and I do know that we have to delete the resource with DestroyIcon when closing the element which embedded it. What I don't know is that if the CImageList automatically calls this on the added elements or not? I did not find exact answers to this to date.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree that using a tool that can help you distinguish what kind of resource is leaking (font, bitmap, brush, pen, etc) will make your job a whole lot easier. Also resources selected into DCs but not de-selected **before** being deleted are for me the most common cause of leaks.

Comment: I used one, and found some special cases where this leak occurred. Then I searched for other places where we have similar problems and found this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CImageList will release all the elements when it is released. Based on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5e0cc8.aspx), If the image list was created with the new operator, you must destroy the CImageList object when you are done with it, which means in the descontructor of CImageList, it release all its elements.

You can try to use  [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=26798) to debug memory/GDI leak issues, it's better than just looking into the code to identify a leak.